# Best approach to reduce checkpoint size for broadcast state

Tags: flink-streaming

I have fairly large broadcast state (about 62MB when serialized as state). I noticed that each instance of my operator is saving a copy of this state during checkpointing. With a parallelism of 400, that's 24gb of checkpoint state, most of it duplicated.

This matches the description of [Important Considerations](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/#important-considerations) in the docs. On the other hand, [Checkpointing under backpressure](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/checkpointing_under_backpressure/#certain-data-distribution-patterns-are-not-checkpointed) says:

> Broadcast partitioning is often used to implement a broadcast state which should be equal across all operators. Flink implements the broadcast state by checkpointing only a single copy of the state from subtask 0 of the stateful operator. Upon restore, we send that copy to all of the operators. Therefore it might happen that an operator will get the state with changes applied for a record that it will soon consume from its checkpointed channels.

The bit about "checkpointing only a singe copy of the state from subtask 0" doesn't match what I'm seeing, hoping someone can clarify.

Regardless...is there any typical workaround for this? For example, I could set up my TMs with one slot (even though they have 8 cores), and then use a thread pool to process incoming non-broadcast elements. This would reduce by 8x the parallelism of the operator. Assuming I deal with concurrency issues (threads accessing state while it's being updated), what other issues are there? E.g. can the collector be saved & then safely called asynchronously by a thread? I don't have watermarks, but wondering about things like checkpoint barriers.

Or I could bail on using a broadcast stream, and replicate the data myself (with carefully constructed keys), but that's also a helicopter stunt.

Answer (score 1):

The bit about "checkpointing only a single copy of the state from subtask 0" is incorrect (I verified this with the author of that sentence). In the current implementation of BroadcastState all operators snapshot their state.

I'm afraid that doesn't help answer your real question, but hopefully clarifies the situation.

Comment: Hi David - thanks for following up. And yes, I tried with unaligned checkpoints and wound up with the same size state.

Comment: So I guess you haven't heard of anyone successfully using 1 slot/TM and doing their own multi-threading for record processing, right?

Comment: No, and I think it's a crazy idea. :) I have seen people try to implement their own state sharing across slots in a multi-slot TM, but I don't recommend it. It generally ends in tears.

Comment: Yes, it does smell like something that's "fraught".